# Saving from Shiny renderDataTable

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, tabletools

This question has been asked previously [R shiny dataTables with TableTools and other extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510671/r-shiny-datatables-with-tabletools-and-other-extensions) and [Use TableTools for DataTables in R Shiny for renderDataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944607/use-tabletools-for-datatables-in-r-shiny-for-renderdatatable) but I am currently struggling getting this demonstration of TableTools to download the csv or xls from a shiny app.  The button appears to work and the csv/xls option is available but nothing happens.  The only thing I could think of was updating the datatables version from 1.9.4 to 1.10.1 but still nothing.  All the other paths are up to date unless I am making some silly mistake.  Thank you.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
runApp(
  list(ui = basicPage(
    h1('Diamonds DataTable with TableTools'),
    tagList(
      singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
      singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/js/TableTools.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
      singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/js/ZeroClipboard.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
      singleton(tags$head(tags$link(href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/css/TableTools.min.css',rel='stylesheet',type='text/css'))),
      singleton(tags$script(HTML("if (window.innerHeight < 400) alert('Screen too small');")))
    ),
    dataTableOutput("mytable")
  )
  ,server = function(input, output) {
    output$mytable = renderDataTable({
      diamonds[,1:6]
    }, options = list(
      "sDom" = 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
      "oTableTools" = list(
        "sSwfPath" = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
        "aButtons" = list(
          "copy",
          "print",
          list("sExtends" = "collection",
               "sButtonText" = "Save",
               "aButtons" = c("csv","xls")
          )
        )
      )
    )
    )
  })
)
```

Comment: not sure if your code is correct. No button appear for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After pouring over this, I have discovered my initial error.  Embarrassingly, the primary issue was that I was trying to save directly from the rstudio launch of the shiny app.  I have since learned that this is impossible because rstudio does not have flash.  As such, **the initial solution was to simply run the app and then open it in a browser with flash installed.**  The save button then works appropriately and I can save a filtered dataset.

However, during my efforts I have discovered some simplification that others may find useful.

The next version of shiny will use the more recent 1.10.2 DataTables.  You can download the current dev version from the [github page](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny).  This allows one to omit the zeroclipboard file after updating the links for the other source files.  Below is the final code I have found works when opened in a browser with the most recent shiny package.  Please note, the slight change in notation as the DataTables 1.10.x has converted to camelCase notation.  Coversions from the old notation are found [here](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert).

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
runApp(
  list(ui = basicPage(
    h1('Diamonds DataTable with TableTools'),
    tagList(
      singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
      singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
      singleton(tags$head(tags$link(href='//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/css/dataTables.tableTools.css',rel='stylesheet',type='text/css'))),
      singleton(tags$script(HTML("if (window.innerHeight < 400) alert('Screen too small');")))
    ),
    dataTableOutput("mytable")
  )
  ,server = function(input, output) {
    output$mytable = renderDataTable({
      diamonds[,1:6]
    }, options = list(
      "dom" = 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
      "oTableTools" = list(
        "sSwfPath" = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
        "aButtons" = list(
          "copy",
          "print",
          list("sExtends" = "collection",
               "sButtonText" = "Save",
               "aButtons" = c("csv","xls")
          )
        )
      )
    )
    )
  })
)
```

**EDIT**

As of DT 0.1.5x the interface has changed following the TableTools updates.  You now use the **Buttons** extension.  **Note** - this still (3/29/16) requires the user to install from [github](https://github.com/rstudio/DT) until the author deems the updates sufficient for pushing to CRAN.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

runApp(
  list(ui = basicPage(
    h1('Diamonds DataTable with DT'),
    dataTableOutput("mytable")
  )
  ,server = function(input, output) {
    output$mytable = renderDataTable({
      diamonds[,1:6]
    }, 
    extensions = 'Buttons',
    options = list(
      "dom" = 'T<"clear">lBfrtip',
      buttons = list('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print')
    )
    )
  })
)
```

Comment: The save button does not do anything when saving as either csv or excel. I've tried doing this by running the shiny app through a browser.

Comment: @BlackMilk please see my edits.  The interface has changed recently.  The provided edits work for me.