# store dataset filtered using DataTables in Shiny in app

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

To perhaps save a few people a minute or two ... this question is about DataTables in a Shiny app (http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/datatables.html) and not Data.Table

I would like to access the index of rows available in DataTables in Shiny. I do *not* want to save the filtered data as a csv file but, rather, add the data.frame to a dropdown of datasets the app user can work with. I am using reactive values to store data.frames and I don't expect too much trouble adding the file/data to the dropdown list once I can access the data.frame (or row index).

Although, again, I do not want to rely on tabletools or similar, to save data to disk, there are several questions related to mine (see link below). However, there *must* be an easier way to access the filtered data-frame in a shiny-app. If not, perhaps there should be :)

I was hoping I might be able to use renderDataTable but I am not sure how that would work.

[Saving from Shiny renderDataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25554068/saving-from-shiny-renderdatatable)

Comment: Seems like it is in-the-works but not there yet: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/shiny-discuss/pprNREvXLG4

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @yihui this is now possible using the DT package and `input$tableId_rows_all` where `tableID` is the id assigned to your table. See the link below for details.

http://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html